# Angular ng-repeat filtering

Tags: angularjs

I have a deeply nested object. I have some records which contain 2 fields that show keys of object properties. I also have select needed to search records by property of object and input to search by key of object. So if I choose option1 and type in input some text, it will be shown the matches in the first field (not second!). And it's similar for second field.  

**How I try to realize:** 
I wrote a filter http://plnkr.co/edit/z9DEmfYz2grW9UonLcFK?p=preview

```
.filter('appFilter', function() {
    return function(value, select, input) {

      var result = [];
      input = input.toLowerCase();
      var reg = new RegExp(input,'g');    

      if (angular.isArray(value)) {
        if (input === '' || $scope.isFiltering) {
          return value;
        } else if (select.value === 'Sequence') {
          for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            if (value[i].Sequence.toLowerCase().match(reg)) {
              result.push(value[i]);
            }
          }
            return result;
        } else if (select.value === 'ID') {
          for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            if (angular.isArray(value[i].Document)) {
              for (let j = 0; j < value[i].Document.length; j++) {
                if (value[i].Document[j].ID.toLowerCase().match(reg)) {
                    result.push(value[i]);
                 }
              }

            }
          }
          return result;            
        } else {
            console.log('error');
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

In controller I set to select's ng-model first option: `$scope.selectParameter = $scope.parameter[0];` 
In debug I set to input parameter some value (123 for example).
So I searching record by first field that contains 123 value. And result finds and pushes the object. But in browser shows anything. 
What's the problem? And I can't avoid the empty option with '?' value in my select :(

**UPDATED**
Nearly solve my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/z9DEmfYz2grW9UonLcFK?p=preview 
It filters by appropriate field and input value. But I faced with another troubles.
 
When input is empty it doesn't show any record. And second is when I choose second option (ID) filter duplicates some records.
Also I try to switch off filter without clearing the input text by clicking on checkbox. 
It's what I want to do but it doesn't work:

```
else if (input === '' || $scope.isFiltering) {
    return value;
}
```

`$scope.isFiltering` is `ng-model` for checkbox input

Comment: I posted plunker too http://plnkr.co/edit/z9DEmfYz2grW9UonLcFK?p=preview . So here is whole project. How can I modify the filter?

Comment: Empty option problem: `<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectParameter" 
              ng-options="item as item.key for item in parameter">
      </select>`

Comment: Thanks. It helped. Also need to add in controller `$scope.selectParameter = $scope.parameter[0];` and ng-options need to `track by item.value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using angulars default filter. I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but maybe it helps a little.

```
.filter('appFilter', function($filter) {
  return function(value, select, input) {
    if( !angular.isDefined(input) || input.length < 1) {
      return value;
    }

    // Angulars "filter" lets you pass in a object-structure to search for nested fields.
    var query = 
        (select.value === 'Sequence') ?
            {Sequence:input} : {Document:{ID:input}};

    return $filter('filter')(value, query);
  }
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Egkw9bUvTPgooc0u2w7C?p=preview

Comment: And if I want to switch on/off filtering by clicking on checkbox, how can I realize it according to your code?

Comment: Need to return value if filter is switched on: `if( !angular.isDefined(input) || input.length < 1 || $scope.isFiltering) {
      return value;
    }` it doesn't work

Comment: Aha, so that was what isFiltering was about. I suppose I would pass in one more argument then, even if it's not super pretty. `if( !angular.isDefined(input) || input.length < 1 || !isFiltering) { return value; }` and `appFilter:selectParameter:isFiltering:inputQuery`

Comment: Oh! It works if I add scope parameter to linked fucntion. And: `| appFilter:selectParameter:inputQuery:this `

Comment: And finally a version with a service instead of passing in all those arguments to the filter. http://plnkr.co/edit/aTJ5xOlgPaYnQEvWpRwH?p=preview Maybe the HTML is a bit more readable and it's easier to use in some other controller I guess... but I'm not sure it was worth the effort! Take care!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I're amazing :)